# Tensor Network from Lattice

Tags: gravity, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, tensor-network

I read an article about tensor networks and they seem very interesting and a promising approach to studying the relations between entanglement, gravity and quantum information. **How does this network relate to Anti de Sitter space? Is it because this network and ADS are both hyperbolic? Thanks!**

[image]

Comment: There are too many questions here. I suggest you narrow it down to only one. At the meantime you can look at some holographic spacetime papers from the past few years.

Comment: be warned, AdS is just a toy mathematical model. Our universe is more closely described as dS. Is not yet entirely clear if all the nice and clever holographic dualities that apply in AdS can be carried out for dS without substantial hailover

Comment: As @Ali said, focus on a core question rather than going all over the place, in order to get meaningful answers

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys, I edited my question. Hopefully it's more succinct now!

Comment: Is there a particular source where you got this diagram from?

Comment: https://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/research/research-initiatives/tensor-networks-initiative

Comment: Note that it has been argued that MERA have certain shortcomings in describing AdS, and might in fact correspond to dS geometries, see e.g. the intro of https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03513.